# How to await completion of replacement page routes

Tags: flutter

If I push a new page route. Then from within this second page, I push a replacement page.
This immediately returns the first route as completed.

But I want to take action after returning to the first page. How am i meant to do this.
If the initial route completes, before i have returned to the initial page?

Comment: `NavigatorObserver` maybe?

Comment: wut do you mean? you are using `Navigator.pushReplacement`? But you want the future to complete after the replacement instead of after the replacement+push? then why not do it yourself with `Navigator.pop` and `Navigator.push`?

Comment: pskink - this is interesting, it's an extremely complicated solution tho. 

scrimau - no, you are missing the question, read again pls

Comment: not really, you need `RouteObserver`(it extends `NavigatorObserver`) - check the official docs, they have some sample code

Comment: pskink - thanks, i definitely appreciate your suggestion. i am still hoping there is an easier way. i feel like the default navigation should handle this - the way it seems to work feels broken